# What is wrong with my virtualenvwrapper installation?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to setup virtualenvwrapper under Oracle Linux.
Python 3.6 is installed.

My .bashrc file contains this:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/bin/python3.6
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

PATH is set to:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

However when I source .bashrc I get this error:

```
/bin/python3.6: No module named virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.
 
If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/bin/python3.6 and that PATH is
set properly.
```

Everything I have read online suggest the VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON and VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV need setting but they already are.